# Karate post calls failing for karate.jar 1.X.X versions

Tags: karate

I am trying to upgrade from jar version 0.9.6. So far I have tried jar versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0RC1.

I am running into a bizarre issue with all the 1.x.x jars. All my tests involving POST calls are failing with an exception. GET calls seem to work fine. Below is the test that I am running and the exception details:

```
Feature: Add foo

Background: Steps to execute before each scenarios
* url host_url
* configure headers = read(headerfn)

Scenario: Add a foo

* def addfooData = read('addfoo.json')

    Given path fooAddEndpoint
    And request addfooData
    When method POST
    Then status 201
```

The test fails at the POST call. Below is the exception I get::

```
Karate version: 1.0.0
======================================================
elapsed:   2.50 | threads:    1 | thread time: 0.45
features:     1 | skipped:    0 | efficiency: 0.18
scenarios:    1 | passed:     0 | failed: 1
======================================================
```

> > > failed features:
> > > status code was: 500, expected: 201, response time in milliseconds: 384,
> > > response:
> > > {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream'.","exceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","stackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at

The same test works fine with jar version 0.9.6.

Could someone please throw some light on what I am missing here?

Comment: I don't have the time to read all this, maybe someone else here can help. my personal opinion is that no-one can help unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - in the future consider acting on the requests to try RC versions, we spent months on this and it saves everybody all these surprises.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I will submit an issue. If in case you were looking for the exact issue, here goes - POST calls are failing with 1.x.x versions of karate.jar with exception:

response: {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream'."

Comment: Sorry for the long details in the question. RC versions have also resulted in the same error.

Comment: FYI - both your comments above don't help at all

Comment: My bad. I have edited the post with a more concise example

Comment: In the link I posted in my first comment, make sure you read the `FAQ` section, thanks.